# Can't add a simple checkbox in frame 'java AWT'

Tags: java, eclipse, checkbox, awt

I'm learning GUI programming in java AWT and am a bit stuck. I can't add a couple of check-boxes in a frame the code i'm trying is-

```
package awt2;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
public class Checkbox {
public static void main(String args[]) {

    Frame mainFrame= new Frame("Checkbox test");
    Checkbox checkBox1= new Checkbox();
    Checkbox checkBox2= new Checkbox();
    checkBox1.setBounds(100,100,50,50);
    checkBox2.setBounds(150,120,50,50);
    mainFrame.add(checkBox1);
    mainFrame.add(checkBox2);
    mainFrame.setVisible(true);

    }
}
```

The error reckons this on checkBox1.setBounds() and checkBox2.setBounds()-

> The method setBounds(int, int, int, int) is undefined for the type Checkbox

And on mainFrame.add()-

> The method add(Component) in the type Container is not applicable for the arguments (Checkbox)

Can someone explain what these errors are all about and how can i fix them? Also i'm using eclipse IDE and javac version 1.8.0_144

Comment: I suggest you use JFrame instead. A bit more modern. See eg https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28326585/jframe-adding-checkboxes-to-the-screen

Comment: So i suggest you to use JavaFX, it's modern, you have more ordering and you can style it with css.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got a problem because your class is named `Checkbox`,
which is hiding the `java.awt.Checkbox` class.
Just choose another class name, for example `CheckboxTest`:

```
package awt2;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
public class CheckboxTest {

    // your code
}
```